# How to write a file to a device paired via the WebUSB API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, usb, webusb

Is it possible to write a file to a [USBDevice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USBDevice) object after it has been paired in browser? Specifically when the device is mass storage such as a USB Flash Drive or SD card, and a compatible browser (such as Chrome >=61)?

After running the following lines of JS:

```js
const usbDevice = await navigator.usb.requestDevice();

// After selecting the device, and
// assuming that both of these Promises don't throw errors

await usbDevice.open();
```

Can a transfer (whether isochronous or otherwise) be instantiated to write a new text file to the connected mass storage?

If so, what protocol/s would need to be used in order to do so if the data must be sent raw?

Comment: While you _can_ use the WebUSB API to write "file" data, it's designed for [lower-level interactions](https://web.dev/build-for-webusb/). You probably want the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I'll have to research that API and determine whether or not it is suitable for the use case I intend to add this feature for.

I'll adjust or close this question if that API turns out to be a workaround.

Comment: @Bryce what ended up being your solution?

Comment: @PhilLucks I actually ended up switching tech-stacks for the project that I'm working on, however, for the initial prototyping that I was doing in JavaScript jsejcksn's solution was suitable